# Why can't I select an object in this function?

Tags: jquery, object, hide, selector

Following problem: There is a slider and I want to hide the "previous image" and the "next image" button at some points. So there is a counter and I want - for example - hide the prev button on the first slide element. Therefore I created this function:

```
function mark_active_pdf() {                    
        if(start_count==0){            
            $('.bx-prev').hide();            
        }            
}
```

I wanted to write a function and initiate it every time another slide is called (bei clicking next button, prev button, left arrow or right arrow and at the beginning). There will be more if-conditions - for example: at the last slide the next button shall disappear etc.. But i could not select and hide the prev button so far. Firebug showed me that I'm selecting an empty object: `Object[]`

But if I use this function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(start_count==0){ 
        $('.bx-prev').hide();
    }
});
```

the object can be selected (firebug displays: `Object[a.bx-prev]`) and the button vanishs.

So why is that so and how could that be fixed?

Comment: How are you executing the first function? you are most likely executing it before the slide container even exists.

Comment: with mark_active_pdf(); at the same position where i fired the working function. And also in my click and keyup function. I already put a console log before and after it. It runs BUT it doesnt select the element and I dont know why :(

Comment: Because there isn't an element to select. Do you understand what `$( document ).ready(function() {` does?

Comment: Yeah sure. And you were right about that. Now the element can be selected but still it doesnt vanish. I dont get it. I mean even if it couldnt select the element at the start it should be able to when called in the click or keyup function but now I noticed that there isnt a call. My whole script seems to be f*cked up...

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin says, the most likely case is that you are calling your function before the DOM is loaded and the object exists. Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    mark_active_pdf();
});
```

If it works, you know what the issue is

Comment: The problem was that when the function was called the parameter start_count was missing. It should have been function mark_active_pdf(start_count); instead of simply mark_active_pdf();